# Android kills broadcast receivers on system low memory

Tags: android

My app has a broadcast receiver which listens for incoming sms but there is no persistent service.

I think the broadcast receiver is killed when the system is low on memory like when app is forced stop from android setting. I have noticed it after one day on my own phone.

Does android kill broadcast receivers on system low memory?

Is there anyway to enable them again after this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My app has a broadcast receiver which listens for incoming sms but there is no persistent service.

That is fine. There should not be a persistent service in most Android apps.

> I think the broadcast receiver is killed when the system is low on memory

Not those registered via `<receiver>` elements in the manifest.

> like when app is forced stop from android setting

Talented programmers realize that "Force Stop" has nothing to do with "killed when the system is low on memory". On Android 3.1+, "Force Stop" will block all broadcast receivers from being used until the user manually runs an activity again. But, again, when your process is "killed when the system is low on memory", Android does not do the same thing as what happens when you tap the "Force Stop" button.

> Does android kill broadcast receivers on system low memory?

Not those registered via `<receiver>` elements in the manifest.

> So in all scenarios that an app need to run all the time, a service must accompany it to enable broadcast receivers again.

Of course not. What *is* required is for you to stop pressing the "Force Stop" button. If you wish to simulate your process being terminated due to low memory conditions, use something else (e.g., swipe the app off the recent-tasks list on Android 4.0+).

Comment: I have registered receivers in manifest but they stop responding after some time on android 4, so what is the problem?

Comment: What's your idea about Deepak Bala  response?

Comment: @Ali: "What's your idea about Deepak Bala response?" -- much of it is incorrect. Manifest-registered broadcast receivers are not affected by low memory conditions. Alarms do not survive a Force Stop. Having a "long-running service" is an anti-pattern on Android, causing users to specifically use Force Stop to get rid of such apps.

Comment: @Ali: ""I have registered receivers in manifest but they stop responding after some time on android 4, so what is the problem?" -- only the Force Stop button should cause a manifest-registered receiver to stop working. You are welcome to publish a sample app that demonstrates otherwise. It may be that your receiver is getting control, but what you are trying to do in that receiver has issues after a period of time.

Comment: I've noticed `BroadcastReceiver`s being affected on low memory even when they are part of the 'receiver' element on the android manifest. Even the GCMBroadcastReceiver is not spared and all GCM messages for all apps across the phone just stop. My quote on long running operations is directly from the android docs. I've not noticed how alarms behave on a Force stop an my comment was not meant to address that scenario.

Comment: @DeepakBala: "I've noticed BroadcastReceivers being affected on low memory even when they are part of the 'receiver' element on the android manifest" -- you are welcome to provide a sample project that demonstrates this. "Even the GCMBroadcastReceiver is not spared and all GCM messages for all apps across the phone just stop" -- you are welcome to provide a sample project that demonstrates this.

Comment: @DeepakBala:  "My quote on long running operations is directly from the android docs" -- the quote is addressing a scenario such as a broadcast receiver needing to trigger a download in response to a broadcast. A manifest-registered receiver cannot do the download itself (main application thread) and cannot safely fork a thread (no running component). For those cases, an `IntentService` should do the download. This has nothing to do with your claimed issues with manifest-registered broadcast receivers not being called after a period of time.

Comment: @CommonsWare I never said long running operations and manifest-registered broadcast receivers affect each other. That was in response to your statement that 'long running' services are an anti pattern. They are depending on what 'long running' entails.

Comment: @CommonsWare As for the GCM receivers, I'm merely reporting what I observed on a HTC phone running gingerbread 2.3.5 while using and monitoring several apps that consumed large amounts of memory.

Comment: @CommonsWare Does your proposed scenario apply to android 2.2 and 2.3?  one other thing, I use package manager to enable and disable the receivers inside the app, may it cause the problem?

Comment: @Ali: "Does your proposed scenario apply to android 2.2 and 2.3?" -- yes. "I use package manager to enable and disable the receivers inside the app, may it cause the problem?" -- if there is a bug, and you fail to enable the receiver when you think you are, then yes. Otherwise, that should be fine.

Comment: I tested the app by killing it using DBMS and the receivers works OK.

Answer (score 3):

If the app is force stopped or killed due to low memory, then yes  the broadcast receiver will also be affected.

> Once you return from onReceive(), the BroadcastReceiver is **no longer active**, and its hosting process is only as important as any other application components that are running in it. This is especially important because if that process was only hosting the BroadcastReceiver (a common case for applications that the user has never or not recently interacted with), then upon returning from onReceive() the system will consider its process to be empty and **aggressively kill it** so that resources are available for other more important processes.
>
> This means that for longer-running operations you will often use a **Service** in conjunction with a BroadcastReceiver to keep the containing process active for the entire time of your operation.

When your app is restarted, register the receiver once more from the `onResume()` method. Unregister it on the `onPause()` method of your activity. For long running operations, use a `Service`.

Comment: So, It's required to have a service to keep a broadcast receiver alive all the time?

Comment: Does it apply to alarms which triggers a broadcast receiver which are used in widgets?

Comment: Alarms should survive anything since they don't really occupy memory. As for background `Service`s I've seen them killed on low memory. They are still the way to go to run long running tasks, but beyond a certain line the framework can decide to kill it. The usage of the Service is to aid long-running ops as opposed to increasing the lifetime of a receiver. In your case Alarm + Service + BroadcastReceiver should be a safe bet.

Comment: The alarm may survive but the broadcast receiver which receives the alarm may be killed as you said. So in all scenarios that an app need to run all the time, a service must accompany it to enable broadcast receivers again. Thank you so much