# android hidden app strategy

Tags: android, hide, intercept

I'm trying to create an app "hidden" from applications list.
The way i though the user will start the app is through a Receiver listening for NEW_OUTGOING_CALL and intercept a particular number dialed.
The problem is that on new Android versions, this receiver will never be activated if the app never start once. ([Starting the application from a BroadCastReceiver (NEW_OUTGOING_CALL doesn't always work)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122085/starting-the-application-from-a-broadcastreceiver-new-outgoing-call-doesnt-alw)).

I can't figure out a workaround for this problem: the app launcher is totally hidden so the user cannot never launch the app, and the receiver would never be activated if the app will never start.

Is there any other strategy or workaround for hide and launch the app with some kind of secret action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadcast receiver not working in ICS if the app is not started atleast once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952562/broadcast-receiver-not-working-in-ics-if-the-app-is-not-started-atleast-once)

Answer (score 0):

Create a activity with manifest file pointing it as the the Launcher activity and make it transparent and call its `finish` method in onCreate. User clicking on that icon will have no idea that the activity is opened. But why don't you show the **About application** kind of screen in the launcher activity?

Comment: Thanks but I don't want launcher activity at all

Comment: Actually, I would appreciate that update on newer versions as it prevents malicious software from handling the sensitive data. But I can't understand your scenario why you don't need even an icon to indicate that the application is installed.

Comment: Applications like anti thieves tool should be hidden for better security to the stupid thief ...